# How to join datatables of a dataset?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, datarelation

I have a dataset which have four datatables.

- Table[0] contains columns such as: storedProcedure,DLLMethod,BLLMethod
- Table[1] contains columns such as: DLLMethod,BLLMethod
- Table[2] contains columns such as: UCName,BLLMethod
- Table[3] contains columns such as: UCName,Function,Module
- Table[4] contains columns such as: StoredProcedure,Function,Module

I want to join first four tables such that final table must contain StoredProcedure,Function and Module.Can anyone Please help me with C# coding?

Comment: @Prem You have asked many questions. If you feel you have been given useful and correct answers for any of these questions then you should mark those answers as accepted.

Comment: @Prem Also if you accept an answer and you think it is a good answer, up-vote it as well. You have lots of accepted answers with zero votes.

Comment: And inform us how those tables are related. On first view, table[1] is not necessary at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inner join of DataTables in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665754/inner-join-of-datatables-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

LINQ to DataSet

```
dim query = from a in table1 join b in table2 on a.table2ID = b.ID select a,b
```

this can grow on many more tables by adding more joins

```
var query = from a in table1 join b in table2 on a.table2ID = b.ID select a,b;
```

Comment: Thank You very much... Would you please Provide me a more clear c# coding as Im a beginner.