# Deleting rows from DataSet from DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset

This is my scenario the `DataSource` from my `DataGridView` is not linked to a open database, so I am not going to use a `DataAdapter`.

In order to avoid the need to have a constant database connection (to save resources), a user is only able to save changes (i.e., update the database), only when cells/rows are deleted/modified from the `DataGridView`.

My problem comes in here. I have a database with two `DataGridView` objects, resembling a master/detail relationship. The second `DataGridView` has an extra filter that is applied when the user clicks on the master table row, from which all records relating to that specific row will be reflected in the child `DataGridView` (second `DataGridView`).

I have three `DataSets`:

- one for the master table,
- one for the detail table, and
- one for the filtered rows from the second table

The filter is a simple `SELECT` statement:

`DataSet.Tables[TableName].Select(...);`

When deleting rows from the second `DataGridView` (linked to the third `DataSet`), I want that specific row from the third `DataSet` to delete the second `DataSet`.

But I don't know how to link a `DataSet` to other `DataSet` objects.

Or is there another alternative here?

Answer (score 0):

Use DataTable and follow example here:
[Inner join of DataTables in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665754/inner-join-in-datatable-in-c-sharp) to join two or more datatables by using LINQ