# How to go through two tables to create another table with common values

Tags: c#, datatable

First Datatable is dt

```
var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID");
            dt.Columns.Add("First Name");
   dt.Rows.Add(1,"name1");
   dt.Rows.Add(6,"name6");
   dt.Rows.Add(4,"name4");
```

The second table is dt2

```
var dt2 = new DataTable();
                dt2.Columns.Add("ID");
                dt2.Columns.Add("First Name");
                dt2.Columns.Add("Last Name");
                dt2.Columns.Add("Birthday");

       dt2.Rows.Add(1,"name1", "lastName1", 01.01.1991);
       dt2.Rows.Add(2,"name2", "lastName2", 02.02.1992);
       dt2.Rows.Add(3,"name3", "lastName3", 03.03.1993);
       dt2.Rows.Add(4,"name4", "lastName4", 04.04.1994);
       dt2.Rows.Add(5,"name5", "lastName5", 05.05.1995);
       dt2.Rows.Add(6,"name6", "lastName6", 06.06.1996);
```

in the third DataTable dt3, I want to get those values ​​where ID is the same

result:

```
ID   Name   Birthdate
1    name1  01.01.1991
4    name4  04.04.1994
6    name6  06.06.1996
```

how to go through the DataTable's in c# ?

Comment: Why are you not doing this in SQL? Why are you using data tables for your data types?

Comment: If you can use LINQ please have a look at this example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665754/inner-join-of-datatables-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no easy way, AFAIK, to join the 2 tables and get the third table automagically unless you are willing to write some code....

You can join them using Linq first:

```
var common = from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
             join x in dt2.AsEnumerable() on c.Field<string>("ID") equals x.Field<string>("ID")
             select new object[] { c["ID"],c["First Name"], x["Birthday"] };
```

And now you can create the destination table with the schema you want:

```
DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
dt3.Columns.Add("ID");
dt3.Columns.Add("Name");
dt3.Columns.Add("Birthdate");
foreach (var item in common)
   dt3.LoadDataRow(item.ToArray(),true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Write an `SQL Query` or a `Stored Procedure` such that it **joins** the Two tables like you have depicted. Now use that Query for your DataTable with in .Net. You will get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding them to an actual database with a defined schema or just trying to do this in memory?  If memory, I would add these to a DataSet which you can then use to filter the criteria becuase in the dataset, you can define their relationship.

Answer (score -1):

You might be looking for adding Relationship between your tables. Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ay82azad%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

I guess you will need the DataTables to be in the same DataSet (you can add the DataTables into DataSet).

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @RQDQ You want me to post the complete solution instead? you are a funny guy!