# DataTables Dynamic Join

Tags: c#, join, datatable

I search a lot about dynamic join on DataTables,
I found:

[Inner Join With Dynamic Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502512/c-sharp-datatable-inner-join-with-dynamic-columns)

[Inner Join On DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665754/inner-join-of-datatables-in-c-sharp)

[Dynamic Linq To Dynamic Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967101/dynamic-linq-to-join-on-dynamic-columns-on-datatable)

[Join DataTable Support Left-Right-Full](http://blog.csdn.net/ericyeung/article/details/2659633)

But I can't find any general solution, assume this scenario for join two tables:

```
DT1 Left Join DT2 On DT1.Id != DT2.Id
```

Or

```
DT1 Right Join DT2 On ((DT1.Age + 2) = DT2.Age) OR (DT1.BirthDate > DT2.BirthDate))
```

As you see I need some general solution to Dynamically Join between two DataTables with complex Where clause,  I have a Data Structure to support complex Where Clauses, But How can I Join Dynamically? any suggestion?

Comment: Can you show what kind of Linq you already tried?  I have tried something similar, so I can probably help you.

Comment: @Martao I just Know this Type Of Dynamic Linq http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx but this one don't support Dynamic Join

Comment: Agreed, that kind of Dynamic Linq does not really solve your problem. However, I think Bognar's answer might go a long way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11505884/1606813

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ here, if working on 3.0 or above. I know its not correct but just to give you an idea. You need to do some reasearch in this code. Just for help. You have apply `DefaultIfEmpty` to the table from which you want to return null in case no matching records found.

```
var dt = (from dt1  in DT1.AsEnumerable()
          from dt2 in DT2.AsEnumerable().Where(dt1.Id==dt2.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new {
           dt1.Column
          }).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: I don't see any dynamic here

Comment: @SaeidAlizade Then why dont you create a dynamic query and pass the parameters that are required, instead of joining in runtime

Comment: What you mean of dynamic query? dynamic query for sql? the sources of DataTables could be Files, etc