# Joining two DataTables in C# with non matching data

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq

I have two tables in SQL that I populate into DataTables in C#. They SQL tables are housed on different servers and different DB's.

In the first table I have 5 columns

```
Name(string), AgentStatus(string), TimeInState(double), TaskHandled(double), Region(string)
```

The second table I have 3 columns

```
Name(string), CChats(double), AChats(double)
```

I have been using this link to merge the tables in C#

[Inner join of DataTables in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665754/inner-join-of-datatables-in-c-sharp)

However the issue I am having is this.

Table 1 has 59 rows, 1 for each user.

Table 2 has 25 rows, 2 for each user that has a Chat account.

When I merge them in C# I only get the matches from table 1 that match the 25 rows in table 2. I need to show all rows from table1 and if they have a row in table 2 show that data, otherwise display 0's

I know where the issue is, its in the select statement in the link above, but I am not sure how to fix it in C#

Here is my code that does not work......The listbox is just to see the output for debugging.....

```
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

        dt1.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt1.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
        dt1.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(double));
        dt1.Columns.Add("Calls", typeof(double));
        dt1.Columns.Add("Region", typeof(string));

        dt2.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt2.Columns.Add("CChats", typeof(double));
        dt2.Columns.Add("AChats", typeof(double));

        foreach(DataRow dr in _agentStates.Rows)
        {
            DataRow row = dt1.NewRow();
            row["Name"] = dr[0].ToString();
            row["Status"] = dr[1].ToString();
            row["Time"] = Convert.ToDouble(dr[2].ToString());
            row["Calls"] = Convert.ToDouble(dr[3].ToString());
            row["Region"] = dr[4].ToString();
            dt1.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        foreach(DataRow dr in _chatCount.Rows)
        {
            DataRow row = dt2.NewRow();
            row["Name"] = dr[0].ToString();
            row["CChats"] = Convert.ToDouble(dr[1].ToString());
            row["AChats"] = Convert.ToDouble(dr[2].ToString());
            dt2.Rows.Add(row);

        }

        var result = from table1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                     join table2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on (string)table1["Name"] equals (string)table2["Name"]
                     select new
                     {
                         Name = (string)table2["Name"],
                         Status = (string)table1["Status"],
                         Time = (double)table1["Time"],
                         Calls = (double)table1["Calls"],
                         Region = (string)table1["Region"],
                         CChats = (double)table2["CChats"]
                     };
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
           listBox1.Items.Add(item.Name + " " + item.CChats.ToString());

        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to do a `LEFT JOIN` conceptually (which is an `OUTER JOIN`, not an `INNER JOIN`).

> The result of a left outer join (or simply left join) for table A and
>   B always contains all records of the "left" table (A), even if the
>   join-condition does not find any matching record in the "right" table
>   (B).
>
> Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join

Jeff Atwood has also posted [a decent visual explanation](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.htm) of the different joins.

In LINQ this is done a bit more awkwardly than SQL, and is something like:

```
var LeftJoin = from user in Users
join chat in Chats
on user.Name equals user.Name into JoinedTables
from row in JoinedTables.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new                          
{
  Name,
  AgentStatus,
  TimeInState,
  TaskHandled,
  Region,
  CChats = chat != null ? chat.CChats : 0
  AChats = chat != null ? chat.AChats : 0                          
};
```

Source: 
http://codingsense.wordpress.com/2009/03/08/left-join-right-join-using-linq/

Of course joining on `Name` isn't ideal - hopefully you actually have an `ID` in the real world, or can really guarantee that names are both unique and will be provided consistently (e.g. no trailing whitespace or differences in capitalisation).

// EDIT, Addressing updated code sample

Try this:

```
var result = from table1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
             join table2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() 
             on (string)table1["Name"] equals (string)table2["Name"]
             into joinedDt
             from table2 in joinedDt.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new
             {
                 Name = (string)table1["Name"],
                 Status = (string)table1["Status"],
                 Time = (double)table1["Time"],
                 Calls = (double)table1["Calls"],
                 Region = (string)table1["Region"],
                 CChats = (table2 != null ? (double)table2["CChats"] : 0)
             };
```

Comment: The name 'table2' does not exist in the current context, got that for both references to table2 in the CChats line.

Comment: Updated the last `from` line and it works (tested in LINQPad)