# Merging 2 datatables in to 1 datatable with same number of rows.

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i merge two Datatables into the same row. I am using different stored procedures to get data into datasets. In asp.net using c#, i want to merge them so there are same number of rows as table 1 with an added column from table 2.

For example:

```
DataTable table1 = dsnew.Tables[0];
DataTable table2 = dsSpotsLeft.Tables[0];
table1.Merge(table2);
```

This is fetching me 4 rows instead of 2 rows. What am i missing here? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Could you describe the two tables? A list of fieldnames in both may suffice

Comment: So, you're pulling data from 2 tables via stored procs into DataTable objects, then attempting to merge the data.  Can you do it in the stored procs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more about the design of these tables, some of this is speculation.

What it sounds like you want to perform is a `JOIN`. For example, if you have one table that looks like:

```
StateId, StateName
```

and another table that looks like

```
EmployeeId, EmployeeName, StateId
```

and you want to end up with a result set that looks like

```
EmployeeId, EmployeeName, StateId, StateName
```

You would perform the following query:

```
SELECT Employee.EmployeeId, Employee.EmployeeName, Employee.StateId, State.StateName
FROM Employee
INNER JOIN State ON Employee.StateId = State.StateId
```

This gives you a resultset but doesn't update any data. Again, speculating on your dataset, I'm assuming that your version of the Employee table might look like the resultset:

```
EmployeeId, EmployeeName, StateId, StateName
```

but with `StateName` in need of being populated. In this case, you could write the query:

```
UPDATE Employee
SET Employee.StateName = State.StateName
FROM Employee
INNER JOIN State ON Employee.StateId = State.StateId
```

Tested in SQL Server.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use the method `Merge` in this case, instead you should create new `DataTable` dt3, and then add columns and rows based on the table 1 and 2:

```
var dt3 = new DataTable();

var columns = dt1.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                  .Concat(dt2.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>());

foreach (var column in columns)
{
    dt3.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, column.DataType);
}

//TODO Check if dt2 has more rows than dt1...
for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var row = dt3.NewRow();
    row.ItemArray = dt1.Rows[i].ItemArray
                       .Concat(dt2.Rows[i].ItemArray).ToArray();

    dt3.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: Concat is static method of String.Concat

Comment: @shujatAli: Well, it's also a method on Array, please take a look MSDN

Comment: @CoungLe Please take a look at msdn public methods of array http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have table `Category` and `Product` related by `CategoryID`, then try this

```
var joined = from p in prod.AsEnumerable()
             join c in categ.AsEnumerable()
             on p["categid"] equals c["categid"]
             select new
             {
                 ProductName = p["prodname"],
                 Category = c["name"]
             };

var myjoined = joined.ToList();
```

Sources

- [LINQ query on a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable)
- [Inner join of DataTables in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665754/inner-join-of-datatables-in-c-sharp)
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataset/thread/ecb6a83d-b9b0-4e64-8107-1ca8757fe58c/

That was a LINQ solution. You can also loop through the first datatable and add columns from the second datatable