# Joining of Two Datatable into oneDataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, merge

I need to merge two datatable into one common datatable in version C# 3.5 version. I tried merge operation like dt1.merge(dt2). But it is appending datatable2 values into bottom of datatable1. But I need like below format.

```
DataTable1
Column1 Column2 Column3
  1        Row1      Row2
  2        Row3      Row4

DataTable2
Column4 Column5 Column6
  1        Row5      Row6
  2        Row7      Row8
```

Resultant Table should be like

```
DataTable1
Column1   Column2 Column3    Column5  Column6
  1        Row1      Row2   Row5    Row6
  2        Row3      Row4   Row7    Row8
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Show us what you've got so far

Comment: You have got your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628020/merging-2-datatables-in-to-1-datatable-with-same-number-of-rows

Comment: Looks like what you want is in an inner join, possible answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665754/inner-join-of-datatables-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Merge() will merge the data table vertically. You can iterate through first DataTable and append each column to second DataTable. In the following example **tb2** will have all the columns of **tb**.

```
DataTable tb = new DataTable();
DataTable tb2 = new DataTable();

foreach (DataColumn item in tb.Columns)
{
  tb2.Columns.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: If the first DataTable has already columns, you have to check, that the second DataTable doesn't has the same Columnnames.