# How to bind two C# datatables to one ASP: GridView

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have two datatables. I want to display them in one Asp: GridView side by side.

Dt1
Col1 co2

Dt2
Col3 col4

I want GridView to display as
Col1 col2 col3 col4

There is no relationship with those datatables.

Comment: Not going to happen

Comment: Ok, let me explain in another way. Is it possible to bind to dt3 then assigning dt3 to GridView possible?

Comment: yes it is possible with `datatable.Merge`. please see this link it is already answered  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285474/merge-2-datatables-and-store-in-a-new-one

Comment: DataTable.Merge does not join side by side. In my case it is required to assign two datatables side by side not in append style.

Comment: then go for pivot ...as the example given below

Comment: This thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628020/merging-2-datatables-in-to-1-datatable-with-same-number-of-rows, Cuong Le's answer solved this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot table as follows this convert rows as columns

```
INSERT INTO #yourtable ([Id], [Value], [ColumnName])
VALUES
    (1, 'John', 'FirstName'),
    (2, '2.4', 'Amount'),
    (3, 'ZH1E4A', 'PostalCode'),
    (4, 'Fork', 'LastName'),
    (5, '857685', 'AccountNumber');

SELECT
    Firstname, Amount, PostalCode, LastName, AccountNumber
FROM
    (SELECT
         value, columnname
     FROM
         #yourtable) d
PIVOT
    (MAX(value)
     FOR columnname IN (Firstname, Amount, PostalCode, LastName, AccountNumber)
    ) piv;
```

Comment: I do not have access to stored procedures. Please post the code to do in C# code behind.

Answer (score 0):

My demo didn't check empty/null validation. If needed, please do.

```
//Create new class
public class FinalData
{
    public string Col1 { get; set; }
    public string Col2 { get; set; }
    public string Col3 { get; set; }
    public string Col4 { get; set; }

    public FinalData(){}
}

//Populate your two tables into FinalData array as below
int MaxRows = dt1.Rows.Count > dt2.Rows.Count ? dt1.Rows.Count : dt2.Rows.Count;
FinalData[] fdList = new FinalData[MaxRows];

for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    FinalData[i] = new FinalData() { Col1 = dt1.Rows[i]["Col1"].ToString(), Col2 = dt1.Rows[i]["Col2"].ToString() };
}

for (int i = 0; i < dt2.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    FinalData[i] = new FinalData() { Col3 = dt2.Rows[i]["Col3"].ToString(), Col4 = dt1.Rows[i]["Col4"].ToString() };
}

//Bind your gridview with fdList
YourGridview.DataSource = fdList;
YourGridView.DataBind();
```