# C# Dataset - Filling a datarow from another datatable with parameters

Tags: c#, dataset

I'm fairly new to C# so please bear with me...

I have a dataset with 2 tables:

[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8nn6.png)

What I want to do is update the ID on the Cost table where Premises[PremNo] equals Cost[PremNo].

So far I have a foreach that goes through all the rows and updates them, I just don't know how to specify where I need it to update from

```
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[1].Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn ID in ds.Tables[1].Columns)
            {
                row["ID"] = **12345**;
            }

        }
```

I need someone to point me in the direction for the **12345** bit.

ds.Tables[1] is Cost, and ds.Tables[0] is Premises

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Dan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inner join of DataTables in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665754/inner-join-of-datatables-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
 var tblCost = ds.Tables[1];
 var tblPremises = ds.Tables[0];
 foreach (DataRow cost in tblCost.Rows)
 {
    var premRow = tblPremises.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<int>("PremNo") == cost.Field<int>("PremNo")).FirstOrDefault();
    if (premRow != null)
        cost["ID"] = premRow.Field<int>("ID");
 }
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Just had to change the <int> for the PremNo as some of the values contain a /