# Joining two DataTables in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, left-join

I have the following two data tables (DataTable) that represents PC allocations to students for different timeslots:

Table1:

```
Timeslot   PC1   PC2  PC3
1          A           B
2          A           B
3                 D
4                 D
```

Table2:

```
Timeslot   PC1   PC2  PC3
1                 C         
2                 C  
3
4
```

Would it be possible to join these two DataTables together into one DataTable, as follows?

Wanted:

```
Timeslot   PC1   PC2  PC3
1          A      C    B
2          A      C    B
3                 D
4                 D
```

I know that, in SQL, it would be quite straight forward left join, but I have no clue how I can do this in C# with DataTables.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665754/inner-join-of-datatables-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

A bit shorter and more efficient if the result is merged in one of the source tables:

```
Table1.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Join(Table2.Rows.Cast<DataRow>(), a => a[0], b => b[0], 
   (a, b) => {a[1] += "" + b[1]; a[2] += "" + b[2]; a[3] += "" + b[3]; return a; }).Count();
```

Comment: I like it.  The return a to change the original row is blowing my mind... I've never seen that before.  I believe the count function is just to force it to execute, right?  Very nice.

Comment: @Obie yes sure, Count/Last/Max etc. can be used to execute the query instead of foreach loop. The return is only because it has to return something and doesn't really matter what is returned.

Comment: Ahh yes, got it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here it is using LINQ:

```
var joinData = t1.Select().Join(t2.Select(), j1 => j1["TimeSlot"], j2 => j2["TimeSlot"],
            (j1, j2) => new { j1, j2 }).Select(j => new
            {
                TimeSlot = j.j1["TimeSlot"],
                PC1 = (string)j.j1["PC1"] != "" ? j.j1["PC1"] : j.j2["PC1"],
                PC2 = (string)j.j1["PC2"] != "" ? j.j1["PC2"] : j.j2["PC2"],
                PC3 = (string)j.j1["PC3"] != "" ? j.j1["PC3"] : j.j2["PC3"]
            });
        var resultTable = new DataTable();
        addColumns(resultTable);
        foreach(var row in joinData)
        {
            var dr = resultTable.NewRow().ItemArray = new object[] { row.TimeSlot, row.PC1, row.PC2, row.PC3 };
            resultTable.Rows.Add(dr);
            WriteLine($"{dr[0]} {dr[1]} {dr[2]} {dr[3]}");
        }
```