# How to populate Datatable with InnerJoin Sql data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Im trying to populate the table with the following code. but i am not sure of the right way to do it.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.KanbanDatabase))
            {
                DataTable dat = new DataTable();
                dat.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[13] { new DataColumn("O_Date"), new DataColumn("O_User"), new DataColumn("O_Material"), new DataColumn("O_Description"), new DataColumn("O_Sloc"), new DataColumn("O_Supplier"), new DataColumn("O_StandardPack"), new DataColumn("O_KanbanSize"), new DataColumn("O_Qty"), new DataColumn("Entry Date"), new DataColumn("PO"), new DataColumn("O_Urgency"), new DataColumn("Quantity") });
                string SqlQry = "SELECT Kanban_Order.[O_Date], Kanban_Order.[O_User], Kanban_Order.[O_Material], Kanban_Order.[O_Description], Kanban_Order.[O_Sloc], Kanban_Order.[O_Supplier], Kanban_Order.[O_StandardPack], Kanban_Order.[O_KanbanSize], Kanban_Order.[O_Qty], Kanban_GR101.[Entry Date], Kanban_GR101.[PO], Kanban_Order.[O_Urgency], Kanban_GR101.[Quantity]";
                SqlQry = SqlQry + "FROM Kanban_Order, Kanban_GR101";
                SqlQry = SqlQry + "WHERE Kanban_Order.[O_Material] = Kanban_GR101.[Material] AND O_Date BETWEEN @dateFrom AND  @dateTo";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlQry, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateFrom", dateFrom);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTo", dateTo);
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    conn.Open();
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds,dat);
                    Status1.DataSource = dat;
                    Status1.DataBind();
```

This code doesn't work. What else can i do?

Comment: What do you mean the code doesn't work? Can you be more specific as to what your case is? Are you encountering any errors? If yes, please let us know.

Comment: Your `Select` statement needs spaces between each line. If you put that string together end to end there would be no spacing. ie.. `" From` and `" Where`. Use `INNER JOIN`  statement instead of the old style joins.

Comment: hope this link will help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665754/inner-join-of-datatables-in-c-sharp

Comment: No one should be [joining via the where clause](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
private DataTable GetDataTable()
    {
        try
        {
            string strQuery = "Your SQL Query";
            string strConnectionString ="Your Connection String";
            using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Connection = Connection;
                        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        da.Fill(dt);
                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

USE of `GetDataTable` function

```
Datatable dt = GetDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Always have spaces in there. The best way to make sure it works is to debug and check the sql generated and run in SQL server to test if unsure. You will pick it up quickly.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.KanbanDatabase))
            {
                DataTable dat = new DataTable();
                dat.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[13] { new DataColumn("O_Date"), new DataColumn("O_User"), new DataColumn("O_Material"), new DataColumn("O_Description"), new DataColumn("O_Sloc"), new DataColumn("O_Supplier"), new DataColumn("O_StandardPack"), new DataColumn("O_KanbanSize"), new DataColumn("O_Qty"), new DataColumn("Entry Date"), new DataColumn("PO"), new DataColumn("O_Urgency"), new DataColumn("Quantity") });
                StringBuilder _sqlQuery = new StringBuilder("SELECT Kanban_Order.[O_Date], Kanban_Order.[O_User], Kanban_Order.[O_Material], Kanban_Order.[O_Description], Kanban_Order.[O_Sloc], Kanban_Order.[O_Supplier], Kanban_Order.[O_StandardPack], Kanban_Order.[O_KanbanSize], Kanban_Order.[O_Qty], Kanban_GR101.[Entry Date], Kanban_GR101.[PO], Kanban_Order.[O_Urgency], Kanban_GR101.[Quantity]");
                _sqlQuery.Append(" FROM Kanban_Order, Kanban_GR101");
                _sqlQuery.Append($" WHERE Kanban_Order.[O_Material] = Kanban_GR101.[Material] AND O_Date BETWEEN '{dateFrom}' AND  '{dateTo}'");
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(_sqlQuery.ToString() , conn))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    conn.Open();
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds,dat);
                    Status1.DataSource = dat;
                    Status1.DataBind();
```

Comment: `da.Fill(ds,dat);` Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'string'